# DefaultCellStyle would not apply

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I tried to format the cells of 2 Columns in a DataGridView but on the UI you can't see the format.
Here is my Code:

```
gridView.Rows.Clear();
gridView.Columns.Clear();

List<DataGridViewColumn> rowList = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();
DataGridViewColumn col;

foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
    col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    col.Name = GetNameAttribute(info);
    col.HeaderText = GetTextAttribute(info);

    if (GetFieldTypeAttribute(info) == MyFieldTypes.MoneyField)
    {
        col.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Format = "C2", Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight };
        col.ValueType = typeof(System.Double);
    }

    gridView.Columns.Add(col);
}
gridView.Refresh();
```

Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `col.DefaultCellStyle = ` line. Does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: Yes this point get hit

Answer (score 0):

As long as `col.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Format = "C2", Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight };`
 is executed, your code should be working. Try to debug to that point as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution, maybe it is not the best but it works.

When I add the DefaultCellStyle on every row it works:

```
while (dr.Read())
    {
         row = (DataGridViewRow)dgvGridView.Rows[0].Clone();

         row.Cells[dgvGridView.Columns["Key"].Index].Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
         row.Cells[dgvGridView.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();
        // This Line works...
        row.Cells[dgvGridView.Columns["Amount"].Index].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Format = "C2", Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight };

        dgvGridView.Rows.Add(row);
    }
dgvGridView.Refresh();
```